# cell array initialize

Tags: matlab

i have a cell array with elements 22*22,18*18*6,14*14*6,10*10*6,6*6*6.can u please help me to initialize it

**Update:**

```
s{l(:,:,feature_map)=zeros(22,22),zeros(18,18,6),zeros(14,14,6),zeros(10,10,6),zeros(6*6*6)
```

By using the above command first element of cell array is empty.all other elements have 22*22*6 elements.it'l create problems in convolution

code is:

```
num_of_maps_in_layer{1}=1;
for i=1:3
    num_of_maps_in_layer{i+1}=6; 
end
num_of_maps_in_layer{5}=6; 

for l=2:5
    for feature_map=1:num_of_maps_in_layer{l}
        sensitivity{l}(:,:,feature_map)=zeros(22,22),zeros(18,18,6),zeros(14,14,6),zeros(10,10,6),zeros(6*6*6)
    end
end
```

Comment: @user689593: Please read through some of these resources: [How to ask a smart question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question), [Style guide for questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers), [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: In your example, what is `l`? What is `feature_map`? What do you want `s` and its contents to look like (i.e. size, number of dimensions, etc.)? These are the details we need from you, otherwise we're just making blind stabs in the dark.

Comment: i had edited.please help

Comment: @user689593: When you make considerable modifications to your question, please do it such way that it's obvious related to earlier answers. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
sensitivity = {zeros(22,22),...
               zeros(18,18,6),...
               zeros(14,14,6),...
               zeros(10,10,6),...
               zeros(6,6,6)};
```

This creates a 5-element [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html) `sensitivity`. The first cell contains a 22-by-22 numeric array of zeroes, the second cell contains an 18-by-18-by-6 numeric array of zeroes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to initialize the matrices with, but if you just want do declare them and don't really care what they contain, you could do

```
ones(22, 22)
ones(18,18,6)
ones(14,14,6)
...
```

or you could use `zeros` function for 0-filled matrices.

Comment: s{l}(:,:,feature_map)=zeros(22,22),zeros(18,18,6),zeros(14,14,6),zeros(10,10,6),zeros(6*6*6).                                                          by using the above command first element of cell array is empty.all other elements have 22*22*6 elements.it'l create problems in convolution.please help

Answer (score 1):

By any change did you meant by initialization something like this:

```
1> ca= {22* 22, 18* 18* 6, 14* 14* 6, 10* 10* 6, 6* 6* 6}
ca =
{
  [1,1] =  484
  [1,2] =  1944
  [1,3] =  1176
  [1,4] =  600
  [1,5] =  216
}
```

Comment: sensitivity{l}(:,:,feature_map)=zeros(22,22),zeros(18,18,6),zeros(14,14,6),zeros(10,10,6),zeros(6*6*6).                                                              can u please correct this?first element of cell array is empty.all other elements have 22*22*6 elements.it'l create problems in convolution.please help